# Clicking twice to Login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel Socialite, specifically the Google driver to allow people to Login / Register on my website. I've got a really annoying issue where in order to be redirected to the dashboard, you must click the Login button twice.

```
$existingUser = Account::where('email', $user->email)->first();

if($existingUser){
  Auth::login($existingUser, true);
} else {
  $newUser                  = new Account();
  $newUser->id              = strtotime(date('Ymdhis'));
  $newUser->name            = $user->name;
  $newUser->email           = $user->email;
  $newUser->google_auth_id  = $user->id;
  $newUser->save();

  Auth::login($newUser, true);
}
  return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Above is the code I have in my `LoginController`, it checks for an existing account, if one is found, it logs in and if one can't be found, it creates a new account and then logs that in. In both instances, you must click the button twice to be actually logged in. If it creates a new account, clicking it first does actually add the new account to the database but you then must click it again to be taken to the dashboard.

I have tried `return Redirect::intended('/')` but that made no difference.

Comment: if you are using sub domain make sure that your session key start with `.`  it could be a session problem

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using a subdomain

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Have you found a solution to this @JTP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be an answer or not, but I've faced the same issue, and I've solve it on the redirection part, not on the callback part in the `LoginController`.

In your question, you're mentioning the callback part, but in my case, I've added `Auth::logout(); session()->flush();` before the `return Socialite::driver( 'google' )->redirect();`.

```
public function redirect() {
  Auth::logout();
  session()->flush(); # This is my point of this answer.
  return Socialite::driver( 'google' )->redirect();
}
```

BTW, in your case, I think you can ignore my solution, and you may only put `Auth::logout(); session()->flush();` right before your `Auth::login($newUser, true);` for the same effect.